# Elasticsearch: Return same search results regardless of diacritics/accents

Tags: elasticsearch, search, unicode

I've got a word in the text (e.g. `nagymező`) and I want to be able to type in the search query `nagymező` or `nagymezo` and it should show this **text** which contains that word in the search results.
How can it be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a Unicode folding strategy, probably the `asciifolding` filter.  I'm not sure which version of Elasticsearch you're on, so here are a couple of documentation links:

- [`asciifolding` for ES 2.x](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/asciifolding-token-filter.html) (older version, but much more detailed guide)
- [`asciifolding` for ES 6.3](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/analysis-asciifolding-tokenfilter.html)

Comment: Also don't forget to turn on `preserve_original` option in `asciifolding` filter, because it's disabled by default and your search queries will contain words both with diacritics and without it.

Comment: For any solution it is worth testing all four possible cases:

Comment: (1) search for `esta`, DB contains `esta`

Comment: (2) search for `está`, DB contains `esta`

Comment: (3) search for `esta`, DB contains `está`

Comment: (4) search for `está`; DB contains `está`

Answer (score -2):

The trick is to remove the diacritics when you index them so they don't bother you anymore.

Have a look at [ignore accents in elastic search with haystack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593770/ignore-accents-in-elastic-search-with-haystack#23597563)
and also at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/custom-analyzers.html (look for 'diacritic' on the page).

Then, just because it will probably be useful to someone one day or the other, know that the regular expression \p{L} will match any Unicode letter :D

Hope this helps,