# Search with accents in Django with haystack and elasticsearch

Tags: python, django, search, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I've to implement a search engine on a website I'm working on, I discovered that haystack seems to be the best Django library for that, so I implemented it with elasticsearch.

The language of the application is Spanish, so many of you know that there are so many words with accents (á, é, í, ó, ú), and I need haystack to be able to find "canción" if the user types "cancion" (without accent).

Here is my search view (I'm using haystack's autocomplete feature with jQuery typeahead plugin)

```
import json
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet


def autocomplete(request):
    sqs = SearchQuerySet().autocomplete(content_auto=request.GET.get('q', ''))[:5]
    suggestions = [{'title': result.title, 'url': result.object.get_absulute_url()} for result in sqs]
    # Make sure you return a JSON object, not a bare list.
    # Otherwise, you could be vulnerable to an XSS attack.
    the_data = json.dumps(suggestions)
    return HttpResponse(the_data, content_type='application/json')
```

There is nothing special in my settings but the normal configuration of haystack.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django Haystack : search for a term with and without accents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240880/django-haystack-search-for-a-term-with-and-without-accents)

Answer (score 0):

[Haystack supports and provides spelling suggestions for queries](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchqueryset_api.html?highlight=spelling#SearchQuerySet.spelling_suggestion).

```
def autocomplete(request):
    sqs = SearchQuerySet().autocomplete(content_auto=request.GET.get('q', ''))[:5]
    if len(sqs) == 0:
        # if there are no results try with the spelling correction
        suggestion = sqs.spelling_suggestion()
        sqs = SearchQuerySet().autocomplete(content_auto=suggestion)[0:5]
    suggestions = [{'title': result.title, 'url': result.object.get_absolute_url()} for result in sqs]
    # Make sure you return a JSON object, not a bare list.
    # Otherwise, you could be vulnerable to an XSS attack.
    the_data = json.dumps(suggestions)
    return HttpResponse(the_data, content_type='application/json')
```

`spelling_suggestions` should be able to recognise the similarity in `canción` and `cancion` and return some results